# text-decoration command does not works

Tags: html, css

while making navigation tab in the  anchor tag i used the text-decoration:none; command in the css file but the under line and color change still appears for me.Is there any way to remove the under line and color changing

Comment: bro show your code how can any one with this info, better make a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by what you said I will take a guess where you went wrong.

`#text-decoration:none;` is not vaild due to the # in front, you use it in CSS.

Within the style of a div:

```
<div class="test" style="text-decoration:none;">Test</div>
```

Now within style tags:

```
.test {
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

I'm sure from this you will be able to work out how to do what you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

click here **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3hy8M/)**

**css**

```
.lorem a{
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="lorem">
<a href="#">lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: How specific is this related to the OP's issue?

Comment: No worries for english. I got your point. But your example is very general and it obviously is not the OP's issue or else he would have got the solution working. If you check the answer provided by Nopzen, you will know what I am trying to point out. - @Fags

Answer (score 1):

Style like this.

```
ul > li > a {
text-decoration:none
}
```

And it will work 100% unless u have nestede the A really wirede.

Comment: Im useing the > to define a very specfic A tag and not just any A tag in a ul Well my excample does that normaly i would have gone like ul.main-navigation > li > a to remove the decoration on all the a Tags in the list. If u want to remove the first one only apply the pseduo clas :first-child like this ul.className > li > a:first-child { code goes here

Comment: Your right i was confused, but css is confusing :P

Comment: :) No problem, mistakes happens now and then. Better to acknowledge than deny :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would share your actual CSS it would be easy to help you, but for now we have to guess...

Try to remove the hashtag before removing the decoration:

```
linkElement
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

If you select the element by class, use

```
.linkElement
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

If you select the element by ID, use

```
#linkElement
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Make sure you do this one the actual element carrying the underline. If the `A` (hyperlink) has underline, dont select the `LI` covering it:

Wrong example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">underlined words</a>
  </li>
</ul>

ul li
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Right example:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">underlined words</a>
  </li>
</ul>

ul li a
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```